# Quartz threadpool reconfiguration

Tags: threadpool, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz and want to change it's thread pool size via remote JMX call, but unfortunately couldn't find any proper solution. Is it possible to change the configuration of the running job programmatically ?

Answer (score 1):

I used Quartz with spring. In my web.xml I created a spring ContextListener. My app starts the Quartz job and exposes 2 JMX methods to start and stop on demand.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>za.co.lance.admin.infrastructure.ui.util.MBeanContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The MBeanContextListener class like this.

```
public class MBeanContextListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

  private ObjectName objectName;  
  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MBeanContextListener.class);

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
    super.contextDestroyed(sce);
    logger.debug("=============> bean context listener destroy");
    final MBeanServer mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    try {
      mbeanServer.unregisterMBean(objectName);
      logger.info("=============> QuartzJmx unregisterMBean ok");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
    super.contextInitialized(sce);
    logger.debug("=============> bean context listener started");
    final MBeanServer mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    try {
      final QuartzJmx processLatestFailedDocumentsMbean = new QuartzJmx();
      Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler) ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getBean("runProcessLatestFailedDocumentsScheduler");
      processLatestFailedDocumentsMbean.setScheduler(scheduler);
      objectName = new ObjectName("za.co.lance.admin.infrastructure.jmx.mbeans:type=QuartzJmxMBean");
      mbeanServer.registerMBean(processLatestFailedDocumentsMbean, objectName);
      logger.info("=============> QuartzJmx registerMBean ok");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The QuartzJmx class. PLEASE NOTE! Any MBean class (QuartzJmx) must have an interface ending with MBean (QuartzJmxMBean ).

```
@Component
public class QuartzJmx implements QuartzJmxMBean {

  private Scheduler scheduler;

  private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzJmx.class);

  @Override
  public synchronized void suspendRunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob() {
    LOG.info("Suspending RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob");
    if (scheduler != null) {
      try {
        if (scheduler.isStarted()) {
          scheduler.standby();
          LOG.info("RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob suspended");
        } else {
          LOG.info("RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob already suspended");
          throw new SchedulerException("RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob already suspended");
        }
      } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
      }
    } else {
      LOG.error("Cannot suspend RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob. Scheduler = null");
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot suspend RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob. Scheduler = null");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void startRunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob() {
    LOG.info("Starting RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob");
    if (scheduler != null) {
      try {
        if (scheduler.isInStandbyMode()) {
          scheduler.start();
          LOG.info("RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob started");
        } else {
          LOG.info("RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob already started");
          throw new SchedulerException("scheduler already started");
        }
      } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
      }
    } else {
      LOG.error("Cannot start RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob. Scheduler = null");
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot start RunProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob. Scheduler = null");
    }
  }

@Override
  public void setScheduler(Scheduler scheduler) {
    this.scheduler = scheduler;
  }
```

And last, the Spring context

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="runProcessLatestFailedDocumentsTask"
        class="za.co.lance.admin.infrastructure.service.vbs.process.ProcessDocumentServiceImpl" />

    <!-- Spring Quartz -->
    <bean name="runProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass"
            value="za.co.lance.admin.infrastructure.service.quartz.RunProcessLatestFailedDocuments" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="processDocumentService" value-ref="runProcessLatestFailedDocumentsTask" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Cron Trigger -->
    <bean id="processLatestFailedDocumentsTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob" />
        <!-- Cron-Expressions (seperated with a space) fields are -->
        <!-- Seconds Minutes Hours Day-of-Month Month Day-of-Week Year(optional) -->
        <!-- Run every morning hour from 9am to 6pm from Monday to Saturday -->
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 9-18 ? * MON-SAT" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Scheduler -->
    <bean id="runProcessLatestFailedDocumentsScheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="runProcessLatestFailedDocumentsJob" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="processLatestFailedDocumentsTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but the question is how to change thread count programmatically ?

Comment: To change the Thread count - you need to configure a quartz.properties (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/)  go to this link to see the thread property names (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool) use the MBean example above to stop a job, then change the properties file to a new thread count, and use the MBean to start the job again. Quartz will consume the new settings.